# JetBrains IDES: temporarily show excluded directory

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Usually I mark folders like `bower_components` and `node_modules` as Excluded in JetBrains IDEs, so they won't appear in `Search` or `Open file/class/...` dialogs.

But sometimes (few times a day) I need to take a look at code from those folders and only solution I found is to go to Settings > Directories and remove these folders from Excluded and after I look at the code, put them back again.

Isn't there some better workflow? Like excluding folders from all searches, but keeping them in Project view?

Comment: Not sure if there's a way. I can only give a hint on how to faster exclude a directory. You can right-click a directory in Project view and select 'Mark Directory As'->'Excluded'. Just a bit faster than going to Settings. But I'd probably file your case to [their issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you would use **Scopes** instead of excluding folders ?

Comment: I can also suggest adding these folders to javascript libraries (settings/javaScript/Libraries) and then disabling these libraries - this will exclude them from completion/navigation, keeping them visible in the project view. For searching (find in path, etc.) scopes seems to be the best choice (as suggested by @LazyOne). See also [IDEA-23537](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537)

Comment: @Topka: Thanks, I know the shortcut, the bad you have to go to Preferences to un-Exclude to folder

Comment: @LazyOne: Great, didn't about about this feature, it suits better for this. Thanks!